# Using variables for common version numbers in Gradle dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am learning how to use [variables to manage gradle android dependencies library version numbers](https://medium.com/@ivan_m/use-variables-to-manage-gradle-android-dependencies-library-version-numbers-92f0e362a2fc#.52llhlgcn). I like this idea in order to reduce duplication and keep all libraries with the same version number in sync. However, I would also like to continue to get warnings in Android Studio when a newer version of a library is available so that I can decide when to upgrade. How can I both use a variable for the version number and see a warning when a new version is available?

Comment: Nevermind...it seems that Android Studio 2.2.2 does this out of the box.